# android package naming when using different localization assets

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-build-type

Suppose I have an android app, say `com.acme.game`
This app is using different assets to achieve localization.

What will be the best strategy for building this App (apk) ?

Should I create separate projects for each "locale" and name it `com.acme.game.en`, `com.acme.game.rus`...  accordingly,
or there is a better way without any duplication?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a single package name and just add different assets for various locales in appropriate folders. Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization)

Comment: Thanks ! but it does't tell anything about what to do with assets directory :(